# How to init a scroll without returning the result in Elasticsearch.Net 5?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch-net

Since `SearchType.Scan` has been removed in Elasticsearch.Net 5 I can't get my head around how to init a scroll which just return the scrollId and not all documents also. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify `Scroll` on the search request

```
var response = client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .MatchAll()
    .Scroll(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
);
```

or

```
var request = new SearchRequest<Document>
{
    Query = new MatchAllQuery(),
    Scroll = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
};

var response  = client.Search<Document>(request);
```

The response will contain the first set of scrolled documents and a scroll id to use to fetch the next set